# Trying to set boundaries for a parent element so its child element wouldt be able to get out of boundaries

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to make that if the plank is touching the width borders of the with it cant longer move so it wouldnt get out

i tried using if statements after and before the switch, using  getboundingclientrect, and other approaches of using the virables of the element with offsetwidth and such but still sometimes it didnt change a thing and sometimes it stopped the movement of the plank half way through inside the containter

````
    //Declaring virables fo the plank and its bounds
    const plank = document.getElementById('plankIndex');//Getting the plank from HTML



    //Declaring virables fo the container and its bounds
    const container = document.getElementById('containter');
    
    const containterwidth = container.off



    let plankX = 0;//Declaring the position of plank
    let plankSpeedX = 10;//The speed of the movement by the amount of PX we change
    function movePlank(event) {
        switch(event.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                plankX -= plankSpeedX;
                break;
            case 39:
                plankX += plankSpeedX;
                break;
        }


        plank.style.marginLeft = plankX + 'px';
    }```

if needed to attach my entire js and html and css let me know thans in advance!
````

Comment: You shouldn't attach all your code, but if you prepare a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then it will increase the chances that others will be able to help. Perhaps include your attempts at using `getBoundingClientRect` / `offsetWidth` etc.